# Wordpress Featured Image Not Working

Tags: wordpress

I have installed the the_post_thumbnail function into my function.php file. The GUI for the function pops up when I am editing posts, however, whenever I upload a pic, I receive a broken image/link and nothing is actually uploaded. Does anyone know why? Anyone with a similar experience know a quick fix?

Comment: It's hard to really troubleshoot this stuff with no code posted; that said, is the following line in your functions.php file?

`add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); `

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails

Also: Does the Featured Image functionality work in TwentyTen? I'm just wanting to verify it's a theme issue before troubleshooting further.

Comment: Are you able to upload "regular" images as you would to use them in your posts?

Answer (score 0):

Check in other browsers if you are using Chrome, because I had the same issue with Chrome, switch to Safari or you can use Advanced Custom Fields instead of using the Featured image.